# Sketchup Ruby ComponentDefinition.count_instances only in selection

Tags: ruby, sketchup

Given a `Sketchup::ComponentDefinition` object `c_def`, if I use `c_def.count_instances` or `cdef.instances.length` I have the total number of instances of my component in the whole model, just like documentation says it should.

- [ComponentDefinition::count_instances](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/componentdefinition#count_instances)
- [ComponentDefinition::instances](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/componentdefinition#instances)

Unfortunately I need to count instances separating by groups or sub-components.
E.g. suppose I have two different components in a model that use the same basic component.
The first one has 3 basic component instances and the second one has 5.

`c_def.count_instances` will always return 8, as it is the total number of instances, but I need to be able to tell that the first component has only 3 and the second one only 5.

How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You would then need to recursively traverse the `entities` of the instance you're interested in. I'm afraid there is no API method for doing this.

```
module Example

  def self.count_definition_in_entities(entities, find_definition, count = 0)
    entities.each { |entity|
      definition = self.get_definition(entity)
      next if definition.nil?
      count += 1 if find_definition == definition
      count = self.count_definition_in_entities(definition.entities, find_definition, count)
    }
    count
  end

  def self.get_definition(entity)
    if entity.is_a?(Sketchup::ComponentInstance)
      entity.definition
    elsif entity.is_a?(Sketchup::Group)
      entity.entities.parent
    else
      nil
    end
  end

end # module


d = Sketchup.active_model.definitions["Sophie"]
Example.count_definition_in_entities(Sketchup.active_model.entities, d)
```

Also, beware that `count_instances` doesn't a complete full model count. If you have an component C1 placed two times in another component C2. Then `C1.count_instances` return `2`. If you add another copy `C2` you might expect `C1.count_instances` to yield `4` - but it doesn't it still yields `2`. The method only counts how many times the instance is placed in any `Entities` collection, but doesn't take into account the whole model three.